# How we can set proxy in Botium Box, in "Generic HTTP(s)/JSON Connector"

Tags: json, https, automated-tests, ibm-watson, botium-box

Where in the botium Box can we setup the proxy, and how do we  skip the certificate  or attach certificate to HTTPS call of Generic HTTP(S)/JSON Connector.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore certificate errors, set the **NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED** environment variable to **0**

Proxy can be controlled by environment variables (see [here](https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables) for details.

```
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
NO_PROXY
```

UPDATE:
See [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/715849729/I+am+behind+a+corporate+proxy+can+I+use+Botium+Box) for details.